# Switch statement with zero indexing

Tags: r, switch-statement

I want to use `switch` to get a character string, but the values that the expression to evaluated can take are `0:20`. Ideally, I would want something like

```
switch(val,
       0 = "output0",
       1 = "output1",
       2 = "output2",
       .
       .
       .
       20 = "output20")
```

But that doesn't work because `val` is a numeric value. I could do this just using `if` statements, but I would prefer to use the `switch` syntax, as I have read that it is faster and also it is more compact. Is there a function that can do what I want, or is there a way to use `switch` for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of these:

```
val <- "0" # test input

switch(val, "0" = "output0", "1" = "output1")
## [1] "output0"
```

or

```
switch(as.numeric(val) + 1, "output0", "output1")
## [1] "output0"
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work. I prefer the first, as I don't like using `switch` with numeric input very much because I think having to count to figure out what an input does it not the best (I actually thought of the second one before asking the question). Thanks a lot!

Comment: And whoops, the first solution only works if I first convert the input to character. So for me, with my input being generically a numeric value from `1:20`, I have to do `switch(as.character(val), "0" = "output0", "1" = "output1")` for it to give me the output I want.

Comment: The question specifically states that "val is a character value".

Comment: Whoops, sorry! I meant to say that it was a numeric value. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

val <- 2

case_when(
  val == 0 ~ "output0",
  val == 1 ~ "output1",
  val == 2 ~ "output2",
  val == 20 ~ "output20",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_ 
)
## [[1]] "output2"
```

I often make an

```
OTHERWISE <- TRUE
```

and then use that since it reads better.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great function that I had never heard of before. However, for me personally (and of course this probably doesn't apply to others with the same problem), I have decided not to use `dplyr` for the moment, as it broke the heck out of the project I am working on (I actually asked a question about it) and I know how to fix what it broke but I don't know **why** it broke so I am not touching it until I figure that out.

Comment: It can be called w/o doing a `library(dplyr)` just pkg namespace prefix it `dplyr::case_when()`. What likely 'broke' some function name being clobbered. I can understand the reticence to use it given that experience, though.

Comment: Damn, I've seen `::` so much but I never looked up what it is for. Good to know.